# Choosing op-amps with voltage output swing

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, amplifier

For a 2 kohm load, typical output voltage swing  Op-Amp #1 is 13V, and the minimum is 10V with a 15V power supply. Its maximum supply voltage is 22V. Let's say I have another op-amp (Op-Amp #2) that has a typical output voltage swing for a 2 kohm load as well of 12V and a minimum output swing of 10V with a 15V power supply. Which op-amp do I use if I want an undistorted Vout peak voltage of 12.5V? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you study some opamp datasheets, for example the one for the [TL071](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slos080n/slos080n.pdf?ts=1594283231524&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

Note how (in table 6.10) it says: Vcc = +/- 15 V and the output voltage swing with a 2 k ohm load is then +/- 10 V (minimum value). That means that the output can be driven

at least **5 V** lower than +15 V (so +10 V)

and

**5 V** above the -15 V rail (so -10 V)

That "**5 V** distance from the supply" is important, compare that for both opamps and in combination with their **maximum supply voltage rating** you have an idea which one is more suitable.

Using the **minimum value** is important as that means a swing of +/- 10V **or more swing** which is always good.

A **typical** output swing of say +/- 12V means that **on average** this model opamp can output +/- 12V but you can expect that many samples ("monday morning opamps") cannot make it and only can do for example +/- 11 V. That you want to avoid if your product goes into mass-production. So focus on the **minimum** value.

[image]

Comment: Yes but both op-amps mentioned can achieve 12.5V. For op-amp #1, a supply voltage of at least 17.5V and op-amp #2, a supply voltage of 17.5V as well, only difference is their typical output voltage swing

Answer (score 0):

Both amplifiers are guarranteed to produce 10 V into 2k with a 15 V rail. You want an undistorted 12.5 V. Neither amplifier is guarranteed to give it. If you're designing a product for sale, then neither amplifier will do for you.

However, any particular example may give you 12.5 V. If you're building a one-off for yourself, then get one and test it. The one with typically 13 V output is perhaps more likely to give you 12.5 V than the one with typically 12 V output. Try #1 first.

Amplifier #1 seems to have an advantage that it will accept 22 V, so you have the option to increase the rail voltage above 15 V, whereas #2 will not. Do beware though that 22 V might be its absolute max, which is not a recommended voltage to run it on routinely.

Comment: But both op amps can achieve 12.5V with a supply voltage of 17.5V, only difference between the 2 op amps are the typic voltage swing and max supply voltage but both are able to achieve 12.5V Thats why Im not sure if I hould choose one over the other

Comment: @Fiidisks Are you changing your question now to indicate that #2 can be powered from more than 15 V? The fundamental answer stands that #1, with its higher typical, is more likely to deliver a higher voltage than #2. Typical means 'not guaranteed', but 'likely'. That's why professional product designers uses min/max specifications, and a hobbyist can get away with looking at typicals.